# Printing if you have owner, group, or general permissions in C

Tags: c, unix, permissions

I'm working on a project that involves Unix where we have to code in C. So this project deals with forking and executing multiple files in C. The problem that I am having trouble with is how to tell if you have owner, group, or general permissions when executing the file. The output should look like this below.

```
File: .. 
Directory: /root 
You have general permissions: read execute
```

or

```
File: Lab3.c
Directory: /home/users15/sew25545
You have owner permissions: read write execute
```

**I have the file and directory part done so dont worry about that.** 
Now the part where it says "You have general permissions:" is where i struggle. I found out to see your read, execute, and write permissions for owner, group, and user is done like so..

```
    fileMode = fileattrib.st_mode;
    /* Check owner permissions */
    if ((fileMode & S_IRUSR) && (fileMode & S_IREAD))
      printf("Has Owner Read Permission");
   etc...
```

So i get all of the permissions no problem, but how do i tell if they have general permissions, group permissions, or owner permissions. My teacher said a different stat function besides st_mode to compare the owner of the file to the owner of the currently logged in user, and also compare the group of the file to the group of the logged in user.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The st_uid and st_gid fields in the stat structure give you the owner and group of the file; compare them to the values for the currently logged in user. You get those using getuid() and getgid().

Comment: First off thank you for the response, but how do I use those commands to pull up their permissions of both

Comment: I simply do if statements such as if ((fileMode & S_IRUSR) && (fileMode & S_IREAD))
            printf("Read "); to find out permissions of owner, group, and user, but how would i know which user im testing for?

Comment: The tests you wrote do always test against the owner/group of the *file*. You find these out from the st_uid and st_gid fields in the stat structure. If you want to find out the names of the user and group, you can use getpwuid() and getgrgid(), respectively.

Comment: Okay that helps me understand it a bit better, thank you. I still don't really know how to use the names of the user and group to see their permissions also. In this project im looking to compare these different permissions so its crucial that I know each sides permissions (both user and file owner)

Comment: If you could provide me sample code to see the user and group permissions I would GREATLY appreciate it!

Comment: Also, if you want to find out whether the *current* user can access the file, you can use the access() function. For example `access(filename, R_OK)` should return 0 if the current user can read the file.

Comment: That right there is what I was looking for, Thank you so much!